# How to create datetime from date and string in tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a Store Procedure in T-SQL. I want to create a datetime from date and string.

So I have this:

```
DECLARE @DATE AS DATE
DECLARE @TIME AS NVARCHAR(5)

SET @DATE = NOW() /*2017-10-11*/
SET @TIME = '08:00'
```

Now, I want to create this date '2017-10-11 08:00:00'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking something like :

```
DECLARE @DATE AS DATE
DECLARE @TIME AS NVARCHAR(5)

SET @DATE = GETDATE() /*2017-10-11*/
SET @TIME = '08:00'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, @DATE) + ' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, @TIME))
```

**Output :**

```
2017-10-11 08:00:00.000
```

Comment: your code works but the date is wrong. the time is 10 - 11 - 2017 08:00 and not 11-10-2017

Answer (score 3):

This would work:

```
DECLARE @DATE AS DATE;
DECLARE @TIME AS NVARCHAR(5);
SET @DATE = GETDATE(); 
SET @TIME = '08:00';

SELECT CONCAT(@DATE, ' ', @TIME);
```

Or if you want it as `datetime` datatype,

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(@DATE, ' ', @TIME) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Can I use this in a select statement?

Comment: Yes, or you can declare it as a variable and use it from there

Comment: you are use DATE so getdate() is truncated, I get it now, ignore this please

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution whitout string-concatenation:

```
DECLARE @TIME AS NVARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @MINUTES AS INT
DECLARE @DATETIME AS DATETIME = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) /* 2017-10-11 */

SET @TIME = '08:00'
SET @MINUTES = DATEDIFF(MI,
                        0,
                        @TIME) /* Get number of minutes from @TIME */
SET @DATETIME = DATEADD(MI,
                        @MINUTES,
                        CONVERT(DATETIME, @DATETIME)) /* Add the minutes to @DATETIME */

SELECT @DATETIME
```